# What is the minimum value of $|x| + |2x+1|+|3x+2|+\cdots+|99x+98|$?

Tags: absolute-value, maxima-minima

> What is the minimum value of the following?
>   $$A = |x| + |2x+1|+|3x+2|+\cdots+|99x+98|$$

What I've tried so far:

- Since $|x| = |-x| $ it is clear that $|3x + 2|$ = $|-3x - 2|$, $|5x + 4| = |-5x-4|$ and so on.
- Therefore $A \geq -x + 2x+1-3x-2+4x+3-5x-4+\cdots-99x-98 = -50x - 49$ and I'm stuck here.

I'm quite sure it's not the right way to go, but that's what I've tried so far. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Yanko I'm not quite sure, might give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general term is of the form $f_n = |(n+1)x + n|$. For $x > -\frac{n}{n+1} = c_n$ we have $f_n = (n+1)x + n$,  for $x \le  -\frac{n}{n+1}$ we have $f_n = -(n+1)x - n$. The terms $c_0 = 0 > c_n > c_{98} =  -\frac{98}{99}$.

So clearly $A$ will get large if $x>0$ or $x <-\frac{98}{99}$.

So choose some $0 > x > -\frac{98}{99}$. Then $c_{n-1} > x > c_n$ and 
$$A = \sum_{k=n}^{98} [(k+1)x + k] - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} [(k+1)x + k]\\
= (98 - 2n)x +  (\frac12 98 \cdot 99 -  n (n+1))(x+1) \\
= -(98 - 2n)\frac{n}{n+1} +  (49 \cdot 99 -  n (n+1))(-\frac{n}{n+1} +1) \\
= 
\frac{1}{n+1} \left( -n (98 - 2n) + (49 \cdot 99 -  n (n+1))\right) \\
= 
\frac{n^2 - 99 n + 4851}{n+1}$$
and at $n =\sqrt{4951} - 1 \simeq 69.3$ this attains its local minimum   $2 \sqrt{4951} - 101 \simeq 40 $.

So we should look at the neighbouring values to find the exact minimum of $A$ which will occur at some boundary.

For $n = 69$ and with the sum above we have that  $A=\frac{937}{23}\simeq 40.739$.

For $n = 70$  we have that  $A=\frac{285}{7} \simeq 40.714$ which is the lowest value, taken at $x = -\frac{69}{70} \simeq -0.9857$.

Comment: That's quite a lot of Maths. Do you think there's a simpler solution to this question?

Comment: I don't know a simpler one.

Comment: Finally I got it. Thanks for the detailed answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to solve it for the first two terms. Then add the third term. You should see a pattern emerging.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Was my initial method correct?

Comment: You've only given a lower bound, and not an especially useful one: noting that $x > 0$ gives a stronger one.

Comment: Indeed. Try to make cases for the first terms and see when they are positive or negative before applying the absolute values.

Answer (score 0):

If a sequence $a_1\le a_2\le \cdots\le a_N$ is given, it is known (and we can also prove) that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N|x-a_i|
$$ is minimized at the median of the sequence $(a_i)_{i=1}^N$. (Put differently, the least mean absolute deviation estimator is given by the median.) The median is defined to be $a_{\frac{N+1}{2}}$ if $N$ is odd and is equal to any value in $[a_{\frac{N}{2}},a_{\frac{N}{2}+1}]$ if $N$ is even.

In this case, by substituting $x=-z$, the objective function is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N|z-a_i|
$$ where $\{a_i\}=\{0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4},\ldots,\frac{98}{99}\}$. Since $N=1+2+\cdots +99 = 4950$, we should look for $2475$-th and $2476$-th term. Since there are $1+2+\cdots +j=\frac{j(j+1)}{2}$ terms in $$\{0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\ldots,\frac{j-1}{j},\frac{j-1}{j}\},$$ we know that there are $2485$ terms in
$$
\{0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\ldots,\frac{69}{70},\frac{69}{70}\}.
$$ This shows that $2475$-th and $2476$-th terms are $\frac{69}{70}$, and hence the minimum is attained by $x=-z=-\frac{69}{70}$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is piecewise linear, the minimum value, if it exists, must occur at one of the transition points (and it's straightforward to notice that for large values of $|x|$, the sum is large, so indeed the minimum value does occur).

Thus, the minimum value is achieved at $x =  \frac{1}{n} - 1$ for some $n \in B = \{1,\ldots, 99\}$.

Now, at some $x \in (\frac{1}{m+1} - 1,\frac{1}{m} - 1)$ for some integer $m$ between $1$ and $98$ inclusive, the derivative of $A$ is given by

$$\sum\limits_{i=m+1}^{99}i - \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}j = \dfrac{(99-m)(100+m) - m(m+1)}{2} = 4950 - m - m^2,$$
which is $0$ when $m = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{19801}}{2}$. One of the solutions is negative, the other is between 69 and 70. Thus, $A$ is decreasing on all of $(-\infty, \frac{1}{70}-1)$ and increasing on all of $(\frac{1}{69}-1,\infty)$, so our minimum is at either $x = \frac{1}{69}-1$ or $x = \frac{1}{70}-1$. Evaluating these two, we find that $$A\left(\frac{1}{69}-1\right) = \sum\limits_{i=70}^{99}\left(\frac{i}{69} -1\right) + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{69}\left(1-\frac{i}{69}\right)=\frac{937}{23}\approx 40.739\mbox{, and}$$
$$A\left(\frac{1}{70}-1\right) = \sum\limits_{i=71}^{99}\left(\frac{i}{70}-1\right)+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{70}\left(1-\frac{i}{70}\right) = \frac{285}{7} \approx 40.714,$$

hence our minimum is at $x = \frac{1}{70}-1$, with a value of $\frac{285}{7}$.